# Issue while converting oci_fetch_assoc data to json

Tags: php, json

I am trying to fetch data from Oracle table and convert to JSON object so that it can be read on Jquery Datatable. This is my PHP code -

```
    <?php

   $db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521)(SEND_BUF_SIZE=)(RECV_BUF_SIZE=))(LOAD_BALANCE=yes))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))" ;

    if($c = OCILogon("test", "test", $db))
    {

        $rowfetch = oci_parse($c, "select * from table" );
        oci_execute($rowfetch);
    while($row=oci_fetch_assoc($rowfetch))
            {
                $arr['data'][]= $row;
                $senddata= json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                echo $senddata;
}
}
    else
    {
        $err = OCIError();
        echo "Connection failed." . $err[text];
    }


OCILogoff($c);
?>
```

I am getting JSON response like this -

> {"data":[{"SCHEMA":"TEST","TABLE_NAME":"TEST_T","CUSTOMFIELD10":"CREATING","CUSTOMFIELD5":"NIK","CUSTOMFIELD9":"NIK","LAST_UPD_TIME":"27-JUN-18"}]}{"data":[{"SCHEMA":"TEST","TABLE_NAME":"TEST_T","CUSTOMFIELD10":"CREATING","CUSTOMFIELD5":"NIK","CUSTOMFIELD9":"NIK","LAST_UPD_TIME":"27-JUN-18"},{"SCHEMA":"TEST","TABLE_NAME":"ART_CM3_T","CUSTOMFIELD10":"Average DWP","CUSTOMFIELD5":null,"CUSTOMFIELD9":"BILLING","LAST_UPD_TIME":"05-FEB-19"}]}{"data":[{"SCHEMA":"TEST","TABLE_NAME":"TEST_T","CUSTOMFIELD10":"CREATING","CUSTOMFIELD5":"NIK","CUSTOMFIELD9":"NIK","LAST_UPD_TIME":"27-JUN-18"},{"SCHEMA":"TEST","TABLE_NAME":"ART_CM3_T","CUSTOMFIELD10":"Average DWP","CUSTOMFIELD5":null,"CUSTOMFIELD9":"BILLING","LAST_UPD_TIME":"05-FEB-19"},{"SCHEMA":"TEST","TABLE_NAME":"ART_T","CUSTOMFIELD10":"CREATING","CUSTOMFIELD5":"NIK","CUSTOMFIELD9":"NIK","LAST_UPD_TIME":"09-FEB-19"}]}{"data":[{"SCHEMA":"TEST","TABLE_NAME":"TEST_T","CUSTOMFIELD10":"CREATING","CUSTOMFIELD5":"NIK","CUSTOMFIELD9":"NIK","LAST_UPD_TIME":"27-JUN-18"},{"SCHEMA":"TEST","TABLE_NAME":"ART_CM3_T","CUSTOMFIELD10":"Average DWP","CUSTOMFIELD5":null,"CUSTOMFIELD9":"BILLING","LAST_UPD_TIME":"05-FEB-19"},{"SCHEMA":"TEST","TABLE_NAME":"ART_T","CUSTOMFIELD10":"CREATING","CUSTOMFIELD5":"NIK","CUSTOMFIELD9":"NIK","LAST_UPD_TIME":"09-FEB-19"},{"SCHEMA":"TEST","TABLE_NAME":"ART_CUST","CUSTOMFIELD10":"CREATING","CUSTOMFIELD5":"NIK","CUSTOMFIELD9":"NIK","LAST_UPD_TIME":"09-FEB-19"}]}

But this is not the correct format that Datatable can read & accept. For Jquery Datatable, JSON Response should be like this -

> {
>     "data": [
>       [
>         "Tiger Nixon",
>         "System Architect",
>         "Edinburgh",
>         "5421",
>         "2011/04/25",
>         "$320,800"
>       ],
>       [
>         "Garrett Winters",
>         "Accountant",
>         "Tokyo",
>         "8422",
>         "2011/07/25",
>         "$170,750"
>       ],
>       [
>         "Herrod Chandler",
>         "Sales Assistant",
>         "San Francisco",
>         "9608",
>         "2012/08/06",
>         "$137,500"
>       ],
>       [
>         "Rhona Davidson",
>         "Integration Specialist",
>         "Tokyo",
>         "6200",
>         "2010/10/14",
>         "$327,900"
>       ],
>       [
>         "Colleen Hurst",
>         "Javascript Developer",
>         "San Francisco",
>         "2360",
>         "2009/09/15",
>         "$205,500"
>       ],
>       [
>         "Haley Kennedy",
>         "Senior Marketing Designer",
>         "London",
>         "3597",
>         "2012/12/18",
>         "$313,500"
>       ],
>       [
>         "Tatyana Fitzpatrick",
>         "Regional Director",
>         "London",
>         "1965",
>         "2010/03/17",
>         "$385,750"
>       ]
>     ]
>   }

What I am doing wrong here? How to change this JSON format to required format of Datatable?

Comment: You sure you're querying the correct table? Also, seems you want [`oci_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/function.oci-fetch-row.php) instead of `oci_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Yes, I am querying from the correct table. the 2nd JSON I gave just for example. Now I tried with oci_fetch_row(). Here is the format I received -
{ "data": [ [ "TEST", "TEST_T", "CREATING", "NIK", "NIK", "27-JUN-18" ] ] }{ "data": [ [ "TEST", "TEST_T", "CREATING", "NIK", "NIK", "27-JUN-18" ], [ "TEST", "ART_CM3", "Average DWP", null, "BILLING", "05-FEB-19" ] ] }

This is also not in correct format.

Comment: I have also tried to replace like this - 
$a = '] ] }{ "data": [ [';
$b = "],[";
$senddata = str_replace($a,$b,$senddata);

But is not replacing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the while loop after appending a returned record, it is echo'ed it.

Asides from returning the wrong format, that is returning duplicate records.

You can output individual rows after encoding them and output the encoded JSON array that they are contained in.

```
echo '{"data": [';

$row = oci_fetch_row($rowfetch);
while ($row) {
    $senddata = json_encode($row, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    echo $senddata;

    $row = oci_fetch_row($rowfetch);

    if ($row === FALSE) break;

    echo ',';
}

echo ']}';
// Remember to free the statement and close the connection.
```

You could also build the array of encoded records and output that altogether.

```
$records = [];

oci_fetch_all($rowfetch, &$records, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW + OCI_NUM);

$resp = ["data" => $records];

echo json_encode($resp, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
// Remember to free the statement and close the connection.
```